# Inserting Labels in Bokeh

Tags: bokeh

I am trying to inser labels in Bokeh and it is not working.

My code is:

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.models import NumeralTickFormatter

df_carteira_grafico = df_resumo_1
df_carteira_grafico['mes_status'] = (df_carteira_grafico['mes_juncao'].astype(dtype=str))+' - '+df_carteira_grafico['Atraso']

output_notebook()
p=figure()
carteira = df_carteira_grafico['mes_status']
tamanho = df_resumo_1['Valor a Entregar']

p = figure(x_range=carteira, plot_height=300, title="Status_Carteira")
p.vbar(x=carteira, top=tamanho, width=0.9)

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.y_range.start = 0
p.yaxis[0].formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format="0.0")

show(p)
```

I am getting this:

[image: graph no labels]

I want to get this:

[image: graph labels]

Tks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

If you put your data in a `ColumnDataSource` yourself, then that source can be used to drive both the `vbar` and a `LabelSet` as [demonstrated in the documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#labels). Something like:

```
# CDS can also be created directly from data frames, but not clear in your case 
source = ColumnDataSource(data=
    dict(carteira=carteira, tamanho=tamanho, labels=[str(x) for x in tamanho])
)

p.vbar(x='carteira', top='tamanho', width=0.9, source=source)

labels = LabelSet(x='carteira', y='tamanho', text='labels', y_offset=5, source=source)

p.add_layout(labels)
```

However please note that I could not actually test this directly, because the example code in your question was not self-contained and complete. Hopefully it points the way, though.

See [Providing Data for Plots and Tables](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html) for more information about Bokeh data sources.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. For thse who may need in the future, here is the code:

```
bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.models import NumeralTickFormatter
from numpy import pi
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import LabelSet

df_carteira_grafico = df_resumo_1
df_carteira_grafico['mes_status'] = (df_carteira_grafico['mes_juncao'].astype(dtype=str))+' - '+df_carteira_grafico['Atraso']

output_notebook()
p=figure()
carteira = df_carteira_grafico['mes_status']
tamanho = df_resumo_1['Valor a Entregar']


source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(carteira=carteira, tamanho=tamanho, labels=[str(x) for x in tamanho]))

p = figure(x_range=carteira, plot_height=400, title="Status_Carteira")
p.vbar(x='carteira', top='tamanho', width=0.9, source=source)


labels = LabelSet(x='carteira', y='tamanho', text='labels', y_offset=5, source=source)

p.add_layout(labels)

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.y_range.start = 0
p.yaxis[0].formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format="0.0")


show(p)
```